# Can I use an environment variable in a Dockerfile USER statement?

Tags: docker

So my Dockerfile is written like so:

```
# set env vars for linux user
ENV LINUX_USER="kbuser"
...
... # other stuff
...
USER kbuser
```

But I would like to use

```
USER $LINUX_USER
```

So that I only have to write the username in one place in the file. But this doesn't work.

How can I get around this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`ARG` directive](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg). As per docs:

> `ARG <name>[=<default value>]`
>
> The ARG instruction defines a variable that users can pass at build-time to the builder with the docker build command using the `--build-arg <varname>=<value>` flag. If a user specifies a build argument that was not defined in the Dockerfile, the build outputs a warning.

So you can actually use `ARG` like so:

```
ARG user=kbuser
USER $user
```

And you can actually set the argument when building the docker image:

```
docker build --build-arg user=banana .
```

There is much more to it in the docs, so you better read thoroughly.

Comment: Thanks! Works flawlessly!